# Automapper, how to make this custom List<KeyValuePair> mapping generic?

Tags: c#, automapper, keyvaluepair

I've got the following mapping working with for key value pairs based on construct using:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<KeyValuePair<MenuTable, List<RoleTable>>,
         KeyValuePair<Menu, List<Role>>>()
        .ConstructUsing(x => 
           new KeyValuePair<Menu, List<Role>>(
               Mapper.Map<Menu>(x.Key), 
               Mapper.Map<List<Role>>(x.Value)
           )
        );
});
```

So that I can call it like this:

```
return Mapper.Map<List<KeyValuePair<Menu, List<Role>>>>(results);
```

However, this means I need to do this for any time I have such kind of query results. Which could be over 100, and they all use the default flattening for mapping, just in a keyvaluepair collection. How can I make this generic? I haven't quite gotten a grasp on generics in Automapper. The documentation confuses me. I don't see how to declare generic variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually need no mapping at all:

- Generic lists are supported by default: See the sample/fiddle & http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Lists-and-arrays.html
- KeyValuePair<,> objects can be mapped by Automapper as long as the Key and Value objects themselves can be mapped: See the sample/fiddle

The only mapping that could be usefull is a `cfg.CreateMap<MenuTable, Menu>().ForMember(...)` in case a property mismatches.

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/1UILC3

Sample:

```
// Sample classes
public class MenuTable
{
    public string MenuProp1 {get;set;}
}

public class RoleTable
{
    public string RoleProp1 {get;set;}
}

public class Menu
{
    public string MenuProp1 {get;set;}
}

public class Role
{
    public string RoleProp1 {get;set;}
}


public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Mapper config
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {});

        // sample Data
        var menuTable1 = new MenuTable() {MenuProp1="Menu1"};
        var menuTable2 = new MenuTable() {MenuProp1="Menu2"};
        var roleTable1 = new RoleTable() {RoleProp1="Role1"};
        var roleTable2 = new RoleTable() {RoleProp1="Role2"};

        // Map by property name
        var target = Mapper.Map<Menu>(menuTable1);
        Console.WriteLine("Map by property by name: " + target.MenuProp1);
        Console.WriteLine();
        // result: "Map by property by name: Menu1"

        // Map KeyValuePair
        var kvpSource = new KeyValuePair<MenuTable, RoleTable>(menuTable1, roleTable1);
        var kvpTarget = Mapper.Map<KeyValuePair<Menu, Role>>(kvpSource);
        Console.WriteLine("Map KeyValuePair: " + kvpTarget.Key.MenuProp1 + " - " + kvpTarget.Value.RoleProp1);
        Console.WriteLine();
        // result: "Map KeyValuePair: Menu1 - Role1"

        // Map List
        var listSource = new List<MenuTable>() {menuTable1, menuTable2};
        var listTarget = Mapper.Map<List<Menu>>(listSource);
        foreach(var item in listTarget)
        {   
            Console.WriteLine("Map List:" + item.MenuProp1);
        }   
        Console.WriteLine();
        // result:
        // Map List:Menu1
        // Map List:Menu2

        // Combination
        var combinedSource = new List<KeyValuePair<MenuTable, List<RoleTable>>>()
        {
            new KeyValuePair<MenuTable, List<RoleTable>>(menuTable1, new List<RoleTable>(){roleTable1}),
            new KeyValuePair<MenuTable, List<RoleTable>>(menuTable2, new List<RoleTable>(){roleTable2})
        };

        var combinedTarget = Mapper.Map<List<KeyValuePair<Menu, List<Role>>>>(combinedSource);

        foreach(var item in combinedTarget)
        {   
            Console.WriteLine("Combined: " + item.Key.MenuProp1 + " - " + item.Value.First().RoleProp1);
        }       
        // result:
        // Combined: Menu1 - Role1
        // Combined: Menu2 - Role2
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey you are right, I was using an older version so either that or something else was wonky, but I upgraded to the version in your fiddle and could remove those mappings.!